# variable referencing and assignment

Tags: python

Say

```
c = 10
a = b = c
```

and now `a,b` reference `c`, so I thought if `c` changes, so will `a,b`, like

```
c = 123  # change c, then a = b = 123
```

But actually, `a,b` doesn't change at all, why? Now consider a list

```
m = [0]
l = [m]*3
l[0][0] = 1  # just change l[0][0], then l[1:] change
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` and `b` do *not* reference `c`, all three of them reference an object `10`.

That means that executing `c = 123` won't change the object *behind* `c`, it will simply point `c` at a new object `123`, leaving `a` and `b` alone.

In other words, you have originally:

```
a ---+
     |
b ---+---> 10-object
     |
c ---+
```

and executing `c = 123` changes that to:

```
a ---+
     |
b ---+---> 10-object

c -------> 123-object
```

The sooner you grasp that Python really *is* fully object oriented, the faster you'll grok the language :-)

The reason why your second sample changes all the elements in `l` is because all the items in the `l` list reference the single `list1` rather than *distinct* backing objects:

```
l -------> list2 {list1, list1, list1}
m -------> list1 {0-object}
```

Executing `l[0][0] = 1` is identical to executing `m[0] = 1` (see below), which will not change the *binding* of `m` to its list, or the binding of those items within `list2` to `list1`, but rather simply change the item *within* `list2` to be a `1-object`:

```
l -------> list2 {list1, list1, list1}
m -------> list1 {1-object}
```

Hence you can see that the change to the contents of the `list1` affects everything. The transcript showing that `l[0][0]` and `m[0]` are equivalent is shown below:

```
>>> m = [0]
>>> l = [m] * 3
>>> m
[0]

>>> l
[[0], [0], [0]]

>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1]]

>>> m
[1]

>>> m[0] = 42
>>> l
[[42], [42], [42]]
```

Note that if you change the *binding* of `m`, that won't change the actual bindings in `list2`:

```
>>> m = [999]
>>> l
[[42], [42], [42]]
```

When you do that, you end up with:

```
l -------> list2 {list1, list1, list1}
           list1 {42-object}
m -------> list3 {999-object}
```

Comment: Your answer is so good... I only wish the question title was more descriptive so that more people would be more likely to find this answer.